# Setting a custom domain on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a small app (using clojureScriptOne) installed on Heroku, I have a custom domain for our programming group that is a ".org" domain, when I try to set the nameserver on my DNS providers control panel to point to "myapp.herokuapp.com" I get the following error:

The nameserver you tried to add is not registered with the .ORG registry as a valid nameserver. Please check the nameserver and try again.

Does this mean that with Heroku one can not use .org domains? I've looked at the documentation, there is no reference to anything other than .com domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"myapp.herokuapp.com" is not your nameserver. You need to register your "example.org" domain with a registrar and delegate the nameservers to a DNS provider such as DynDNS or AWS Route 53.

Then you can create a CNAME from "www.example.org" to "myapp.herokuapp.com".